# CSS: absolute positioned element causes scroll

Tags: html, css, css-position

In [THIS](http://jsbin.com/datucoxasi/edit?html,css,output) scenario, I don't want the last `.child`'s `.hang` to add up to the height and incur additional scroll. I want it to protrude outside `.parent` instead, on scroll.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the parent to stay the size you have it, but you want the last child to have a smaller hang, you can use the css pseudo-class selector [`:last-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp).

It sounds like you want to change the overflow-y of the `child` class that is the last child of its parent.  If you change it to `:hidden`, it should do what you are expecting.

```
.child:last-child {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

See this [JS-Bin](http://jsbin.com/yegekonudi/1/edit?html,css,output) for an example.

---

**EDIT**

In response to the modification of the question, I see that you want to have the `.hang` protrude outside of the `.parent` object.  If I'm understanding your desired look correctly, you have a `.hang` as a child of `.child`, which itself is a child of `.parent`, and you want the overhang from `.hang` to protrude outside of the outer `.parent` object.

Unfortunately, I do not believe this exact behavior is possible.  Once you use `overflow-y: scroll`, then any part of any child that extends beyond the bounds of the container is truncated, and you have to scroll it into view.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you can change:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

to:

```
overflow-y: visible;
```

That'll flow the `.hang`s ouside the `.parent` without a scrollbar.

Comment: I want `.parent` to be scrollable. I just don't want the additional scroll because of `.hang`.